# Silverstripe - How to Allow Comments For A Blog Entry

Tags: comments, blogs, silverstripe

I'm setting up my first ever site in Silverstripe and I'm having trouble with the silverstripe blog module (https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog/tree/0.3).  I've installed it and the two supporting modules comments (https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-comments) and grid-field-bulk-editing tools and they all seem to have installed without incident.  Finally, I've checked the box in the setting for my blog holder and my first test blog post to allow comments. However, when I go to that test blog post I see no way for a reader to post any comments.  What did I miss?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide!

Comment: Hi sszee. Welcome to StackOverflow and to SilverStripe. I hope we can help you but first I have a few questions. Did you installed the 0.3 branch of the SilverStripe blog? The 0.3 branch is for an old version of SilverStripe, version 2.3. The latest version of SilverStripe is currently 3.1. What version of SilverStripe are you using? If you are using SilverStripe 3.1 you should install the master branch of the blog module.

Comment: Did you use composer for installing the modules? See http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/getting_started/composer/ for more information about usage of composer.
Did you flush and ran a dev/build after installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the module, then re-installed it with composer as wmk suggested and it seems to work now. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @sszee, it's good to see you solved your problem. Could you mark your answer as the accepted answer please?